# ValueError: time data '0000-00-00 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, wordpress, datetime

I am trying to convert my WordPress site to a static site generator using the program [exitwp](https://github.com/thomasf/exitwp). But during the conversion process, I always get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exitwp.py", line 374, in <module>
    write_jekyll(data, target_format)
  File "exitwp.py", line 296, in write_jekyll
     i['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=UTC()),
   File "/Users/xxxxx/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '0000-00-00 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

I am not a Python programmer but I looked up what the time data format means and it seems to me that '0000-00-00 00:00:00' DOES MATCH the format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'.

Any idea what is wrong? Help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`%Y` matches years in the range `0001` through to `9999`, see the [table in the module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> `%Y`
>   Year with century as a decimal number.
>   0001, 0002, …, 2013, 2014, …, 9998, 9999

Your year `0000` falls outside of that range.

The same issue applies to `%m` and `%d` (the acceptable ranges are `01` through to `12`, and `01` through to `31`, respectively).

That's because `datetime.datetime()` objects have the same range for their attribute values, there is no `datetime.datetime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` object. `datetime.datetime.min` is set to `datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)` (so `0001-01-01 00:00:00`).

Presumably `0000-00-00 00:00:00` means 'no date available'; you'll have to alter the input to replace those dates, or handle that value to replace it with something else (perhaps `None` would be acceptable?)

Comment: this save my day! Thank you @Martijn Pieters